# Как сделать чтобы вывод из потока не мешал вводу из главного потока?

Tags: java

В данном примере если вводить текст его будет кусками переносить вместе с выводом. Как сделать так чтобы при выводе из потока набранный текст оставался на месте.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class testThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            System.out.println("LOG message");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        new Thread(new testThread()).start();
        while (true){       
                String str = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println(str);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте иначе сформулировать вопрос. В данный момент не ясна суть вашей проблемы

Answer (score 1):

в вашем случае никак нельзя, сообщение `LOG message` будет добавляется после введенного вами текста.

Вам нужно добавить следующий обработчик событий:
если ввели что-то, то ждать до тех пор. пока не нажмут на `enter`. 
при этом нужно кэшировать лог и собирать сообщения

ответ на комментарий снизу
Интерфейс `KeyListener` позволит отловить все.

```
@Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 13) // enter code 
        isPresed = true;
    else {
        isPresed = false;
        System.out.println("not enter");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            if(!isPresed) {
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                System.err.println("LOG message");
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else
                sb.append("LOG message\n");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: как определить что что то ввели и еще не нажали enter?

Comment: @croll обновил ответ

Comment: я так понял что KeyListener работает только с GUI. А с консолью что придумать?